# How to print the number of observations into an external file - selection with where applied?

Tags: sas

I have a messy data set which contains roughly 100 variables and a couple of thousand observations. To check for errors in the data set - I am only interested in a selection of it - I use a `proc print statement` with `where selection` The output of the print goes then into a `*.rtf` file for later reference. Everything works fine so far, `MWE:`

```
data test;
input a b ;
cards;
2 2
3 4
;
run;

ODS rtf file="test";
title "how many obs";
proc print data = test;
var a;
where a=2;
run;

ODS rtf close;
title;
```

However, when there are no errors (i.e. nothing qualifies in the `where selection`, like for instance `where a = 4` in the above `MWE`), I want to print something like "there are no errors" into the `*.rtf`. Right now, there is only an empty file generated.

I have no idea how I could achieve this. I thought maybe `where`has some sort of output (at least in the log it says `0 observations have been selected`) but I couldn't pipe this information into the `*.rtf`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another step that will print something when there are no observations that satisfy your selection criteria.

```
ods rtf file="test";
title "how many obs";
proc print data = test;
  var a;
  where a=2;
run;
data _null_;
  file print;
  if eof then put 'No observations match criteria.';
  else stop;
  set test end=eof;
  where a=2;
run;

ODS rtf close;
```

Comment: Great, works! Just a short follow-up: the first `proc print step` is clear. But how does the `data _null_ step` work? You create a temporary variable `eof` for the `test` data, ok. But how does this work together with the `where a=2` in the next line? I feel like I don't really understand how SAS processes this.

Comment: SAS knows before it gets to the SET statement whether there are any more observations to be read.  Some type of look ahead.  Similar to how LAST. flags know whether the next observation is in the same group or not..